# Setting time limit during accessing data from url in java

Tags: java

I am reading data from url continuously but the problem is that while running the program, it stops to access data from url.

I want to set time limit inside each thread so that if data doesn't come in within that time limit then program will restart.

Please anyone can give code in java?

Comment: Could you paste the code that you have so far so we can advise you how to modify it to do what you want?

Comment: Log the starting time of each thread somewhere and remove it when the thread finishes. Then use another thread to check which thread has timed out (current time - thread's start time > timeout) and kill/interrupt that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes: 
- [java.util.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) 
- [java.util.TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html)

like this [program](http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/prog2/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html)

Comment: Answers should include code rather than linking to code hosted on other sites.  External links have a tendency to become unreachable over time.